# fat arrow in Idris

Tags: syntax, idris

I hope this question is appropriate for this site, it's just about the choice of concrete syntax in Idris compared to Haskell, since both are very similar. I guess it's not that important, but I'm very curious about it. Idris uses `=>` for some cases where Haskell uses `->`. So far I've seen that Idris only uses `->` in function types and `=>` for other things like lambdas and `case _ of`. Did this choice come from realizing that it's useful in practice to have a clear syntactical distinction between these use cases? Is it just an arbitrary cosmetic choice and I'm overthinking it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, in Haskell, type signatures and values are in different namespaces, so something defined in one is at no risk of clashing with something in the other. In Idris, types and values occupy the same namespace, which is why you don't see e.g. `data Foo = Foo` as you would in Haskell, but rather, `data Foo = MkFoo` - the type is called `Foo`, and the constructor is called `MkFoo`, as there is already a value (the type `Foo`), bound to the name `Foo`, e.g. `data Pair = MkPair` http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#tuples
So it's probably for the best it didn't try to use the arrow used to construct the type of functions, with the arrow used for lambdas - those are rather different things. You can combine them with e.g. `the (Int -> Int) (\x => x)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because they interpret the `->` symbol differently.
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols):

> `A => B` means if `A` is true then `B` is also true; if `A` is false then nothing is said about `B`

which seems right for case expressions, and

> `->` may mean the same as `=>`, or it may have the meaning for functions given below

which is

> `f: X -> Y` means the function `f` maps the set `X` into the set `Y`

So my guess is that Idris just uses `->` for the narrow second meaning, i.e. for mapping one type to another in type signatures, whereas Haskell uses the broader interpretation, where it means the same as `=>`.